# How to access custom fields in request module in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

When I am trying to post on WordPress using the requests module, only the title, content, stuff is being posted. But the other custom fields (entered in the description) are not getting published.

```
cool = {
'title': 'Kakashi Hatake',
'content': 'It might be the best way to save someone in distress.',
'type' : 'post',
'requerimientos' : '4.1 and up',
'descripcion': {
    "descripcion": "Checking",
    "version": "5.3.1",
    "tamano": "67M",
    "fecha_actualizacion": "April 13, 2021",
    "requerimientos": "4.4 and up",
    "consiguelo": "#",
    "novedades": "S"
},
    'status': 'publish'
}
r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers=header, data=cool)
print(r)
```

Comment: I'd check the spelling of some of your fields to make sure they match what wordpress is expecting. For example `descripcion` may have to be `description`

Comment: @scotty3785 I checked it. Actually, that's how it has been stored. They are named in the Spanish language.